# Need chat bubble design in react native

Tags: react-native, view, flexbox

I need a chat bubble design as shown in image:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do using view I tried but it doen't work

Answer (score 0):

If this was the web I'd say use CSS to create the box with a pseudo-element for the triangle.

Since React Native doesn't support CSS pseudo-elements, I'd do a regular `<View>` for the chat bubble (adding `borderRadius` to it) with `<Text>` inside, then try something like: https://github.com/Jpoliachik/react-native-triangle to make the triangle and, use `position: 'absolute'` to align it to the bottom of your container View.

If you absolutely need a border, that might be a bit trickier since now you're using two different elements, and the bottom border would continue where you want a space. I'd suggest trying to use slightly different background colors for the views instead?